# Exclude specific errors from custom error redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a good way to exclude some errors from being redirected to the default custom error page?

I'm using aspnet membership provider and have just discovered that if for example a user tries to change their email address to one that is already in the system, rather than show the error message warning in the style of a validation error as was designed, since I turned on custom errors, it just redirects to the standard error page.

Do I need to specifically exclude error codes for this problem?

Here is the custom error section in the web config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/Error500" />
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the exception bubbling up in this case, and implement some validation to check if the email address exists.

Your call to `CreateUser` should return a `MembershipCreateStatus` as an error code.

```
 MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus.aspx) for more error codes.

Comment: Thanks - you're right I wasn't handling the error correctly.  Rookie mistake.